# How to query BIOS using GRUB?

Tags: c++, c, kernel, bios, grub

I am trying to make a small kernel for 80386 processor mainly for learning purpose and want to get the full memory map of the available RAM.

I have read that it is possible and better to do so with the help of GRUB than directly querying the BIOS.

Can anybody tell me how do I do it ?

Particularly, for using bios functionality in real mode we use bios interrupts and get the desired values in some registers , what is the actual equivalent way when we want to use GRUB provided functions ?

Comment: See http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Memory_Map_Via_GRUB and http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the process I use in my kernel (note that this is 32bit).  In my bootstrap assembly file, I tell GRUB to provide me with a memory map:

```
.set MEMINFO,  1 << 1                   # Get memory map from GRUB
```

Then, GRUB loads the address of the multiboot info structure into `ebx` for you (this structure contains the address of the memory map).  Then I call into C code to handle the actual iteration and processing of the memory map.  I do something like this to iterate over the map:

```
/* Macro to get next entry in memory map */

#define MMAP_NEXT(m) \
            (multiboot_memory_map_t*)((uint32_t)m + m->size + sizeof(uint32_t))

void read_mmap(multiboot_info_t* mbt){

    multiboot_memory_map_t* mmap = (multiboot_memory_map_t*) mbt->mmap_addr;


    /* Iterate over memory map */

    while((uint32_t)mmap < mbt->mmap_addr + mbt->mmap_length) {

        // process the current memory map entry

        mmap = MMAP_NEXT(mmap);
    }
}
```

where `multiboot_info_t` and `multiboot_memory_map_t` are defined as in the Gnu multiboot.h file.  As Andrew Medico posted in the comments, [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Memory_Map_Via_GRUB) is a great link for getting started with this.